# Python SUDS return type other than XML

Tags: python, json, suds

I am working with a somewhat non-standard SOAP webservice.  Most of the calls to the webservice return the standard SOAP XML as you would expect, but one call in particular returns a JSON string instead.  This fouls up the xml parser on the client side.

My question is; is there a way to designate the return type on a particular webmethod in SUDS so that it does not try to run it through the xml parser?  I just want the raw JSON response.

Comment: The return type is designated within the WSDL. Any way you can provide visual examples of what you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Python JSON encoder to validate first if it is JSON before feeding it to the XML parser.

```
try:
    json.loads(json_to_test)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid json"
```